# How to Iterate nested json using Array.map from .json file in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have categories and sub categories menu in .json file and I want to iterate these menu using Array.map method, I am able to iterate through categories menu but getting "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error for sub categories menu, what am i doing wrong?

.json file

```json
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Mobiles",
    "image": "img_url",
    "subCat": [
      {
        "id": "591",
        "name": "iPhone"
      },
      {
        "id": "592",
        "name": "Samsung Mobiles"
      },
      {
        "id": "593",
        "name": "Huawei Mobiles"
      },
      {
        "id": "716",
        "name": "Nokia Mobiles"
      },
      {
        "id": "717",
        "name": "Oppo Mobiles"
      },
      {
        "id": "393",
        "name": "View All Brands"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Categories Component:

```js
import CategoriesMenu from '../../CategoriesMenu.json';

<ul>
  {CategoriesMenu.map((cat) => (
            <li key={cat.id}>
              {cat.name}
              <div>
                {CategoriesMenu.subCat.map((subcat) => (
                  <div key={uuidv4()}>
                    <Link to={`/${subcat.name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-')}/${subcat.id}`}>
                      {subcat.name}
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
```

Comment: If it is `{cat.id}` and `{cat.name}`... Why should `CategoriesMenu.subCat.map()` then iterate over the sub-categories of that particular category? `CategoriesMenu.subCat.map()` -> `cat.map()`

Comment: I tried `cat.map()` it is throwing `cat.map is not a function` error

Comment: Then `cat` is not an array as you've shown. Check all elements in `CategoriesMenu` if `subCat` is always an array. If not, adjust your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `CategoriesMenu.subCat.map`, CategoriesMenu is the main Array and should not use.

Change it to `cat.subCat.map`